# Formatting a filename in python

Tags: python, string, format

I would like to format a string based on the input. For example if the line count is 1, the output must be `image00001.png` and if the line count is 400, the output is `image00400.png`

I use the following to do so

```
filename = "image%05d.png".format(line_count)
```

but it doesn't work as expected. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are mixing different formatting specifications. For `.format`, use [Format string syntax](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-string-syntax).

```
line_count = 1
filename = "image{:05d}.png".format(line_count)
```

or the new f-string method

```
line_count = 1
filename = f"image{line_count:05d}.png"
```

Answer (score 0):

You confuse the notation for the substitute operator `%` and for the `.format()` method. The right use of the method is `filename = "image{:05d}.png".format(line_count)`. An even better way is to use a format string: `filename = f"image{line_count:05d}.png"`.

Answer (score 0):

In Python 3 you may use f-strings:

`filename = f'image{line_count:05}.png'`

Answer (score -1):

```
fname = "image" + str(400).zfill(5) + ".png"
print(fname)
```

Comment: The number to zfill tells how many characters wide, the unused MSB characters are filled with zeros